# JavaScript getting ONLY cookie value from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, puppeteer

Essentially, I have a whole puppeteer script which at the end, I get it to log it's page cookies which returns me this:

```
[ { name: 'cookie_name',
value: 'I WANT THIS VALUE ONLY',
domain: 'cookie domain',
path: '/',
expires: -1,
size: 43,
httpOnly: true,
secure: true,
session: true } ]
```

That array is stored as the variable **sessionCookies**, and what I want to do is only log the cookie value, which is shown above as "I WANT THIS VALUE ONLY".

I'm looking for something along the lines of `console.log(sessionCookies.cookie_name.value);` but I'm open to any parsing or any other solutions, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter for the cookie name and get the first entry found.
Like:

```js
let sessionCookies = [{ 
  name: 'name_of_the_cookie_you_want_to_get',
  value: 'I WANT THIS VALUE ONLY',
  domain: 'cookie domain',
  path: '/',
  expires: -1,
  size: 43,
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true,
  session: true
 }]

let myCookieValue = sessionCookies.filter(function(cookie) {
  return cookie.name === 'name_of_the_cookie_you_want_to_get'
})[0].value

console.log(myCookieValue)
```

But take care it will throw an array out of bounds if the cookie has not been found or it does not exist.

Comment: just curious where you're pulling that cookie variable from? This doesnt seem to be working probably because of that

Comment: I changed it to a working script. 
The 'cookie' variable is just a temporary iterator and stands for each element in the list. Similar to 'i' in a for loop.
You can also name it different like 'tempCookie' or just 'e' or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Another non-ES6 solution:

```js
const sessionCookies = [
  {
    name: 'cookie_name',
    value: 'I WANT THIS VALUE ONLY',
    domain: 'cookie domain',
    path: '/',
    expires: -1,
    size: 43,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    session: true 
  }
];

console.log(findCookie('cookie_name'));

function findCookie(name) {
  for (let i in sessionCookies) {
    if (!sessionCookies.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      continue;
    }
    if (sessionCookies[i].name === name) {
      return (sessionCookies[i].value);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with array methods like `forEach()`, `filter()`, `find()`, etc. is that their iteration can't be stopped, so they are less performant in some scenarios.